# Alpha decay radioactivity

Tags: nuclear-physics

Do electrons actually escape from a radioactive element ?

Or simply the helium nuclei that ?

what actually is the structure of a fully decayed radioactive element ?

Comment: while only the helium nucleus moves out , wont the electrons stay in the atom that has undergone decay ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alpha particle really GETS OUT from the unstable nucleus, and what remains is the so-called daughter nucleus. See for instance the reaction

108Te -> 104Sn + alpha,

where the numbers are the atomic masses of the respective elements.
The daughter nucleus, here Sn, remains in some cases in its ground state, and in other cases, also in an excited state and emits additional particles, eventually gamma rays.

The emission of an electron is named beta decay.

Comment: The emission of an electron from the nucleus is beta decay.  If the alpha "just disappears" from the nucleus, the atom is left with two spare electrons, which quickly would result in auto-ionization, getting rid of at least one electron. That electron leaving is not beta decay. In real life, with a 2+ charged alpha heading out of the nucleus, one would imagine some disturbance in the electron cloud and some possibility of an electron leaving with the alpha. But I'd need to think on that some more...

Comment: i repeat will there be a decay of electrons in alpha decay. I have seen that He with mass number 4 and atomic number 2 is shown to be removed from the sample. And the remaining radio active element shows a reduction in 2 electrons.

Comment: @JonCuster while only the helium nucleus moves out , wont the electrons stay in the atom that has undergone decay ?

Comment: Well, you have a positively charged alpha blasting out through the electron cloud, at the same time as the electrons are figuring out that life just changed for them since two protons are exiting with the alpha.  I could see the alpha leaving without electrons, grabbing one on the way, and possibly even taking two with it (with lower probability than just getting one). If all the electrons stay with the original nucleus, than the 2- ion will eject one of them fairly quickly.